# How to stop Samsung S7 from wanting to update Android version?

Tags: updates, settings, 8.0-oreo, operating-system, samsung-galaxy-s7

I'm using my old Samsung S7 to test apps (that I develop) on Android 8.0.0 (Oreo).

But every time I come back to my phone the below screen (Program Update) appears and the phone wants to do an system update of Android to a newer version.

**How can I remove the downloaded system update from my Samsung S7?**

**And how can I stop my Samsung S7 from wanting to update Android in the future?**

Program Update:
[image: Program Update]

System Info:
[image: System Info]

System Update Settings:
[image: System Update Settings]

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-prevent-from-auto-upgrading-to-oreo.3751839/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible unless you root your Samsung S7.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. While this is a valid answer, could you [edit] and expand the answer for those who have their devices rooted?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).